# How to stop blazor server, rendering the C# UI Code after button click?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have been working with webforms for a few years now, and decided to jump into the murky world of Blazor... (I think it is brill so far.) But i have recently ran into an issue, where im not sure how to solve.. I guess its due to the rendering engine..

Basically I have a few buttons and textboxes, inside an edit form.. I realised that every time I type into a textbox and click out of it. The UI runs any code blocks. (I thought that was odd, is that the Form, causing it to do so?) If so what are the options around this..

My Page looks like this as standard..

[image]

Now, if i start to type in the Edit option 1 box. and then click Edit answer button.. The page flickers, and my red and green buttons along with the titles disappear.. (Which are being generated by C# code). if i click the button again, this time it does what it is intending to do, code saves the data and then refreshes the page...

[image]

I understand its due to the life cycle somewhere, but not sure how to make them not re-render... As after i click the edit answer button. I have a refresh the whole page method.

Can anyone educate me, how this can be avoided? Many thanks.. My code

```
<div class="justify-content-center">


    @foreach (var QuizItem in QuizDetails)
    {

        @for (int i = 0; i <= indexCount; i++)
        {
            //indexCount = i;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                i++;
                if (temp == 0)
                {
                    temp = i;
                }

                @for (int b = temp; b <= indexCount; b++)
                {

                    {
                        <h3 style="font-weight: bolder">@b @QuizItem.QuizTitle</h3>
                        @if (role == "Edit")
                        {
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@((args) => DeleteQuestion(QuizItem.QuizTitle))">
                                Delete Question @temp
                            </button>
                            <button @onclick="((args) => Show(QuizItem.Position))" class="btn btn-success">
                                Add Question at Position @temp
                            </button>
                        }

                        if (temp <= indexCount)
                        {
                            temp++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    






        <div hidden="@IsAnswers">
        @if (@role != "Restricted")
        {
            <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="@((args) => ShowAnswers(QuizItem.QuizTitle))">
                Show Answers
            </button>
        }
        </div>

        @if (role == "Edit") //show new quiz add here
        {
            @if (QuizItem.Position == clickedQuizPosition)
            {
                <div hidden="@IsShow">
                    <h1>Add A New Question For The @category Quiz</h1>

                    <br/>

                    <EditForm Model="@CreateQuizModel">
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>

                        @*<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category *</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <InputText id="category" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Category"></InputText>
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => CreateQuizModel.Category)"></ValidationMessage>
                        </div>
                    </div>*@
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Quiz Title</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <InputText id="quizTitle" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.QuizTitle"></InputText>
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => CreateQuizModel.QuizTitle)"></ValidationMessage>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtEmail" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer 1 </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <InputText id="option1" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option1"></InputText>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer 2 </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <InputText id="option2" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option2"></InputText>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer 3 </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <InputText id="option3" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option3"></InputText>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer 4</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <InputText id="option4" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option4"></InputText>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer 5</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <InputText id="option5" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option5"></InputText>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @*<div class="form-group row">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>*@
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <button @onclick="SaveAndAddNewQuestionToCategory" class="btn btn-primary">Add A New Question</button>

                        </div>
                    </EditForm>
                </div>
            }
        }


        @if (@role != "Restricted")
        {

            @*@QuizItem.QuizPosition &nbsp;&nbsp;*@

            @if (showAnswers == QuizItem.QuizTitle)
            {

                <ol class="o">
                    
                    @if (QuizItem.Option1 != null)
                    {
                        @if (QuizItem.Option1.Contains("Empty") != true)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option1</li>
                        }
                    }
                    @if (QuizItem.Option2 != null)
                    {
                        @if (QuizItem.Option2.Contains("Empty") != true)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option2</li>
                        }
                    }
                    @if (QuizItem.Option3 != null)
                    {
                         @if (QuizItem.Option3.Contains("Empty") != true)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option3</li>
                        }
                    }
                    @if (QuizItem.Option4 != null)
                    {
                        @if (QuizItem.Option4.Contains("Empty") != true)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option4</li>
                        }
                    }
                    @if (QuizItem.Option5 != null)
                    {
                        @if (QuizItem.Option5.Contains("Empty") != true)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option5</li>
                        }
                    }

                </ol>

            }
        }
    }

</div>
<br />
<br />
@if (role == "Edit" )
{
   

    <h1>EDIT QUIZ</h1>
   
@foreach (var item in QuizDetails)
{
    <EditForm Model="@CreateQuizModel" OnValidSubmit="SaveAndAddNewQuestion">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>


    
        <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Quiz Question -
            <p style="font-weight: bolder">@item.QuizTitle</p></label>
            <div class="form-group row">

               
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <InputText id="quizTitle" Placeholder="Edit The Quiz Question" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.QuizTitle"></InputText> &nbsp;
                        <button @onclick="@(e => EditQuizQuestion(item.QuizTitle, CreateQuizModel.QuizTitle))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Quiz Question</button>
                    </div>

                    @*<ValidationMessage For="@(() => CreateQuizModel.QuizTitle)"></ValidationMessage>*@

                </div>

            </div>



        <ol id="parent" class="o">
           
            @if (item.Option1 != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtEmail" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = @item.Option1 </label>
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                                <InputText id="option1" Placeholder="Edit Option 1" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option1"></InputText>
                                @if (item.Option1.Contains("Empty"))
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option1, CreateQuizModel.Option1, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                 <button @onclick="@(e => DeleteAnswer(item.QuizTitle, null, item.Option2,item.Option3,item.Option4,item.Option5,item.Position))" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Answer</button>
                                }
                                
                             &nbsp;   <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option1, CreateQuizModel.Option1, item.Id))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Answer</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option1 == null)
            {
        <li>
            <label for="txtEmail" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Answer = Empty </label>
            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <InputText id="option1" Placeholder="Edit Option 1" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option1"></InputText>

                       &nbsp; <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option1, CreateQuizModel.Option1, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option2 != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = @item.Option2</label>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                                <InputText id="option2" Placeholder="Edit Option 2" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option2"></InputText>
                                @if (item.Option2.Contains("Empty"))
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option2, CreateQuizModel.Option2, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => DeleteAnswer(item.QuizTitle, item.Option1, null,item.Option3,item.Option4,item.Option5,item.Position))" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Answer</button>
                                }
                                
                              &nbsp;  <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option2, CreateQuizModel.Option2, item.Id))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Answer</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option2 == null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = Empty</label>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                     
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                            <InputText id="option2" Placeholder="Edit Option 2" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option2"></InputText>

                         &nbsp;   <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option2, CreateQuizModel.Option2, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option3 != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = @item.Option3</label>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                       
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                            <InputText id="option3" Placeholder="Edit Option 3" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option3"></InputText>
                                @if (item.Option3.Contains("Empty"))
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option3, CreateQuizModel.Option3, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => DeleteAnswer(item.QuizTitle, item.Option1, item.Option2,null,item.Option4,item.Option5,item.Position))" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Answer</button>
                                }
                                
                              &nbsp;  <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option3, CreateQuizModel.Option3, item.Id))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Answer</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option3 == null)
            {
        <li>
            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = Empty</label>
            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <InputText id="option3" Placeholder="Edit Option 3" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option3"></InputText>

                       &nbsp; <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option3, CreateQuizModel.Option3, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option4 != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = @item.Option4</label>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                                <InputText id="option4" Placeholder="Edit Option 4" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option4"></InputText>

                                @if (item.Option4.Contains("Empty"))
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option4, CreateQuizModel.Option4, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => DeleteAnswer(item.QuizTitle, item.Option1, item.Option2,item.Option3,null,item.Option5,item.Position))" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Answer</button>
                                }
                                
                                &nbsp;<button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option4, CreateQuizModel.Option4, item.Id))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Answer</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option4 == null)
            {
        <li>
            <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = Empty</label>
            <div class="form-group row">


                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <InputText id="option4" Placeholder="Edit Option 5" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option4"></InputText>

                     &nbsp;   <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option4, CreateQuizModel.Option4, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
            }

            @if (item.Option5 != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = @item.Option5</label>
                    <div class="form-group row">

                       
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                            <InputText id="option5" Placeholder="Edit Option 5" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option5"></InputText>
                                @if (item.Option5.Contains("Empty"))
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option5, CreateQuizModel.Option5, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <button @onclick="@(e => DeleteAnswer(item.QuizTitle, item.Option1, item.Option2,item.Option3,item.Option4,null,item.Position))" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Answer</button>
                                }
                                
                              &nbsp;  <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option5, CreateQuizModel.Option5, item.Id))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Answer</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            }
            @if (item.Option5 == null)
            {
                <li>
                    <label for="txtFirstName" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = Empty</label>
                    <div class="form-group row">

                    
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="wrap">
                            <InputText id="option5" Placeholder="Edit Option 5" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option5"></InputText> &nbsp;&nbsp;

                            &nbsp;<button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option5, CreateQuizModel.Option5, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            }
        </ol>
        


        @*<div class="form-group row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>*@
        @*<div class="form-group row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Quiz</button>
            </div>*@
    </EditForm>


    @*<div class="form-group row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>*@
    @*<div class="form-group row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Quiz</button>
        </div>*@

}
```

Comment: You are rendering the buttons based on the value of `role`.  But you don't show how that is getting modified.  Also, you mentioned the text boxes, but don't show that.  I think you will have to show more code.

Comment: A couple of pointers.  Firstly, consider breaking your page down into components e.g. a question component, rather than a monolithic page built from blocks of HTML.  Secondly, the diffing engine  figures out which bits of the page need to get re-rendered. If things are disappearing then re-appearing it's because there's two render events, one without the bits and then one with.  Maybe share your code on Github?

Comment: @sinfella, you are doing it all wrong. This is not the way to code in Blazor. You may create appropriate components for this task. I think the best way to tackle the issues you're facing here is to use a templated component. I've just answered a question about using templated component... Copy and test the code...try to understand what is going on...come up with questions for clarification, and then build your thing as a templated component, modeling it on my code, which is very similar regarding desired functionality.

Comment: Here's the link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66068152/6152891 . You may also consult the docs about templated components.

Comment: well i know my code isn't too great, but im learning, and i will definately look into your options, going forward. I think the issue must lie with the form, as when i click a button without typing any text, its jumps to the method correctly, i am trying to call. if i type text in the input field and click the button. Thats when it seems to have the issue.